# How to manage error reporting as a side effect in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

I'm playing around with Jetpack Compose and I think I have a side effect in my composable, which tries to send an error report when it finds an unexpected value.

For example:

```
@Composable
fun SampleComposable(state: State, text: String) {
    when (state) {
        value1 -> {
            // show composable
        }
        value2 -> {
            // show composable
        }
        else -> {
            // send an error report
        }
    }
    Text(text)
}
```

So I believe whenever `state` or `text` changes, this will recompose. If `state` is an unexpected value, and `text` changes, it will send another error report. So I think there's a side effect in the `else` block.

Is there a way I should be structuring this code so that an error report isn't sent every time?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)):

```
when (state) {
    value1 -> {
        // show composable
    }
    value2 -> {
        // show composable
    }
    else -> {
        LaunchedEffect(state) {
            // send an error report
        }
    }
}
```

`LaunchedEffect` lambda will only be executed once when added to the compose view tree, including removing and reattaching in case your `state` takes a valid value and then reverting to a non-valid one.

Also, by specifying `state` as a key, you can re-run it if two different invalid states appear in sequence.

Note that this lambda is run on a coroutine scope, so you can call `suspend` functions, but the scope will be cancelled once `LaunchedEffect` is removed from the view tree.

Check out more about side effects in [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) and side effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)